# Apache FallbackResource and request path behaviour

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I'm making a simple website with angularjs on a Apache 2.4 webserver. My website folder looks like this:

```
APACHE24\HTDOCS\TEST
|   .htaccess
|   index.html
|
+---js
|       angular-route.js
|       angular.min.js
|       app.js
|
\---partials
        show-gem.html
```

I setup some routes, like these ones:

```
$routeProvider.when("/gem/:gemId", {
    controller: "ShowGemController",
    controllerAs: "showGemCtrl",
    templateUrl: "partials/show-gem.html"
});
```

And i enabled `FallbackResource /test/index.html` into my `.htaccess` file.

### Question:

Whenever I manually enter the URL I get the right page (e.g. I write `http://localhost:8080/test/gem/123` and I get the corresponding page), but how can this happen? Shouldn't I be redirected to `index.html` since `/test/gem/123` is not an existing resource? And how can angular know it should display that particular template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FallbackResource` is, essentially, a short-hand method for rewriting your URIs. As such, there won't be any redirection to `index.html`, but the URI you request will be *mapped* to `index.html`, where Angular can process it.

For more information, refer to the following article:

- http://fideloper.com/apache-fallbackresource

I've always preferred to use `mod_rewrite` to handle this, as it's a lot more fine-grained, and gives you control.